# Rating control in Python

Tags: python, user-interface, wxpython

Does anyone know a useful implementation for a rating control in wxPython / Python ?

I want to have a functionality where user will rate a particular document as being relevant or not-relevant and I want to capture this in a star-based rating system.

Since, I have already done other GUI development in wxPython, it would be really helpful if someone points me how this can be done in Python .

I

Comment: I don't know if such a thing exists, but it should be really easy to build on top of five buttons. I slapped something together in 5 minutes with `Tkinter`; I doubt `wx` would be any harder. Basically, it's a radio button group that shows selection by drawing buttons 0 through i differently, instead of just button i, right?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the interpretation of "useful", there are definitely solutions in the standard library. They will provide you with a usable solution, but not with eye candy or a particularly nice user experience.

- There's [**`wx.Slider`**](http://wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.Slider-class.html) ([example](http://wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.Slider-class.html)), which could easily be utilized. With a given scale the user can give a rating by dragging the slider towards the upper or lower bounds of a numeric scale.
- Another solution is [**`wx.RadioButton`**](http://wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.RadioButton-class.html) ([example](http://zetcode.com/wxpython/widgets/#radiobutton)) representing a group of options of which only one can be selected at a time. This is a usable implementation for labelled options - e.g. select bad, medium or good rating for the document.

If you dislike the options given above, you would probably ending up implementing your own control. This might be a little challenging at first, but could get you the star rating often seen in web applications. You might want to head to [wxPython custom control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2377135/wxpython-custom-control) SO question. A quick search didn't provide me with any existing implementations.